# How to call a specific python script/program from a HTML button using DJango

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, face-detection

I have a face detection program (built on python) and I'm struggling to call such program from inside a web site (built on DJango). In my personal computer, the face detection program can be started with `python eye_tracker`. I have tried the suggested solutions on the web all day long, without any success. What I'm trying to do is pretty simple: create a button on the web site that calls the face detection program (the program is designed to open the personal computer cam in a new window). Could some one help me?

Comment: This might sound like a stupid query but by window you don't mean web browser window, right?

Comment: No. A new window using CV2 stuff.

Comment: I don't think that would be possible or rather I should say allowed. If a browser can execute native scripts, that would be a big hole in security and no browser would allow that.

Comment: There can be a work around to achieve this but that would need a client side server that would launch `python_eye_tracker` when some url is called.

Comment: Ok. What if the question was in relation to just running any python script? What would be the simplest solution?

Comment: Is your server and client always going to be the same machine?

Comment: This is just for experimental purposes. So yes.

Comment: I have not tried something like this in past but i think you can bind another URL with button that calls a view that contains python_eye_tracker code. Or execute shell command from the view using subprocess module, which will launch python_eye_tracker and return success message to the browser.